# insert in SQL table using panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am creating a common function in my DB class that takes a dataframe as a parameter and insert data into one table. I want this function to be reused in other modules as most of other modules does insert into this table. I was thinking to check if the dataframe doesnt has column to insert and then insert null in column. Should I add addition column to my dataframe but that means editing my original dataframe and add additional columns with null values  or other way is to just skip the column name in my insert which will insert null ( columns are nullable) in the table.  What is the best way to achieve this keeping in mind the reusability and applying important object oriented concepts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, fairly easily, if your tables are not too big, following the following flow:

You can do this, fairly easily, if your tables are not too big, following the following flow:

```
ta = pd.read_sql('table', engine) #dataframe that exists already in SQL
tb #new dataframe that has columns that the other dataframe does not have

for i in list(tb.columns):
    if i in list(ta.columns):
        pass
    else:
        ta[i] = 'NULL'

tconso = ta.append(tb)
tconso.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

**UPDATES**

because you state that your data is big, then you can alter the table directly in the sql performing the append outside:

1) import your libraries

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, func, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
```

2) connection:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'...')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
```

3) run query if column is new and push tables after the new columns have been added:

```
ta = pd.read_sql('table', engine) #dataframe that exists already in SQL
tb #new dataframe that has columns that the other dataframe does not have

for i in list(tb.columns):
    if i in list(ta.columns):
        pass
    else:
        query = text('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] ADD ' + i + ' VARCHAR(50)')
        connection = engine.connect()
        connection.execute(query)
        connection.close()

tb.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists=append)
```

**WITH REMOVING THE NEW COLUMNS FROM THE NEW DF**

```
ta = pd.read_sql('table', engine) #dataframe that exists already in SQL
tb #new dataframe that has columns that the other dataframe does not have

for i in list(tb.columns):
    if i in list(ta.columns):
        pass
    else:
        tb.drop(columns=[i])

tb.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists=append)
```

Let me know if this works.
BR

Comment: Thanks for your response.Also, to add one more thing..my dataframe has 1.3 million rows . is it better to not have the column in the insert query and skip insert for that column rather than adding one more column to dataframe. Just wondering if that will affect performance. For ex: if I am expecting a column clma in data frame and if it is not there, create my insert query without the column .

Comment: I understand your problem. You can do this change without taking and replacing the table. Let me update my response.

Comment: If you just want to drop a column, you can use 'df.drop(columns=['new column'])' and it should work.